# how to open a dir which i just created in python few lines above(used current date and time to create the folder)?

Tags: python

datestring = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(datestring)
os.mkdir(datestring)

(now i need to open this folder and create a csv file name as attendance)

f = open(datestring,'Attendance.csv', 'r+')

writer = csv.writer(f)

Comment: You have to define path to file: ```f = open(datestring + '/Attendance.csv', 'r+')```.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use relative path to file. Also, I think you should use `with` statement while operating with files.

```
datestring = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(datestring)
os.mkdir(datestring)

with open(datestring + '/Attendance.csv', 'r+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    # ... your further code ...
```

Comment: thank you very much!!!!! it worked for me but I had to change 'r+' to 'w' to work! thanks again <3